# Swift Collectionview Datasource and Sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

So, I've asked questions about this before, but I think I need more help here, as I'm getting nowhere.

A little summary of my app:

State now:
Users get a list of devices on one viewcontroller and can check which of them they want to see detailed on the start screen.
The IDs of the devices are stored in a single array like this:

`devArray["device1", "device2",..]`.

This Array is stored in the `UserDefaults`. from a `URLSession` the server data is pulled.

Then all is pulled together and

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let colcel = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    let id = devArray[indexPath.row]
    let devListItem = self.devicesFromTheServer.filter { ($0["id"] as! String) == id }[0]
```

The devices are shown in a CollectionView with no sections and users are able to rearrange the cells. This works very good.

My intention now is to give the ability to group devices in sections.
I thought about a dictionary that would then look like this:

```
dict["device1":"sectionA", "device2":"sectionA", "device3":"SectionB"]
```

But I can't wrap my head around how I would go building the Collectionview out of this, and I'm not sure if my Form of Dictionary is the right thing to do...

Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could adopt here. The first one is a 2 dimensional array which is an array containing an array of devices for each section. The other approach is more scalable and allows you to model data along with just your device name.

The second approach is what I have included below.

What you would need would be something like this:

```
/// Defines a section in data source
struct Section {

   // MARK: - Properties

   /// The title of the section
   let title: String

   /// The devices in the section
   var devices: [String]
}
```

Then in your view controller define an array which stores sections as follows:

```
var dataSource = [Section(title: "Section 1", devices: ["Device 1"]), Section(title: "Section 2", devices: ["Device 2","Device 3"])]
```

You can customise this setup by appending devices to each section in separate functions using some of the logic you already have. I have made it simpler just for this answer.

Then add these collection view data source and delegate methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource[section].devices.count
  }

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
  return dataSource.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
  cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.section].devices[indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. what I don't get is if I should change my dict or how I would get it into the struct or the array?

Comment: Well seeing as the section is something that you have defined, you have to add devices to the device array in `Section(title: "Section 1", devices: [<add devices here>]` manually. This would be something you could wrap inside a function to make it cleaner. I have not used a dictionary at all so I think you should not use it for this application.

Comment: yes, it led me in the right direction., thank you for your help